# Can I Use a Variable to ReDim an Array?

Tags: arrays, vb6

I am not entirely sure why I am getting the error message of

> Expecting a dynamic array var

with this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayTest()
    Dim i As Integer, BankList(0) As Variant, x As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(ScreenArray)
        If ScreenArray(i) Like "TR=SUB*" Then
            Debug.Print ScreenArray(i)
            ReDim Preserve BankList(x)    '<<< ERROR LINE
            BankList(x) = ScreenArray(i)
            x = x + 1   'Raise the value for the next occurrence, if needed.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Basically I am attempting to move specific strings from one array to a new array, if certain criteria are met. It's difficult to determine how many strings will be in the new array until running this `For...Next` statement.

If you can't tell from the code, the original array is `ScreenArray` and the new array is `BankList`.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use `List(Of T)`

Comment: @YowE3K Wow I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: I shouldn't have deleted my comment so fast !!  (I started doubting whether I was right, so got rid of it while I checked.  Appears I was right after all.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a dynamic array, do not specify the size in the original declaration.

So use `BankList() As Variant` instead of `BankList(0) As Variant`.